# What does mean "to get {somebody} {something}"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, objects

Could you say if I'm correct translating the following sentence:

> And I'd like to see about getting Harry some contacts.

like

> And I'd like to see about providing Harry with some contacts.

I'm asking this because I couldn't find any hmm... evidence of existence such a language construction (`to get {somebody} {something}`), and not sure about the accuracy of the interpretation.

Comment: Can you give us more context? What contacts are we talking about?

Comment: @Kyle, Basically it's about getting business contacts.

Comment: I would've said "I'd like to get Harry the phone number for so and so", instead of forming the phrase like that.

Comment: Both are correct just the phrase structure that needs to change.

Comment: Maybe "I'd like to see if could get Harry..." Would sound better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To get *somebody* *something*" is to acquire *something* for *somebody*. If it's a physical object, it means you acquire it and give it to them. If it's not a physical object, then the precise meaning will depend on exactly what it is.

Examples:

> "I'm just going to the shop, do you want anything?"
>   "Yeah, could you get me some Doritos?"
>
> "Hey, Harry, I haven't seen you in a while. What brings you here?"
>   "Well, I was trying to my daughter a work experience placement. Any chance you could help out?"

This is, essentially, another way of saying "get *something* for *somebody*".